# “We who are about to die!” — Who owns Marvel Comics Earth-1287?

Tags: marvel, strikeforce-morituri

Within the Marvel Comics Multiverse, Earth-1287 has been designated in the Marvel Official Handbook for the *Strikeforce: Morituri* universe, last seen in 2014’s current rebooted series *X-Force* #4 & 5.
[image: Morituri]

*Strikeforce: Morituri* was initially published as a monthly ongoing series by Marvel Comics, running for 31 issues from December 1986 – July 1989. [Ref. Marvel’s website](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/16255/strikeforce_morituri_1986_-_1989). [And from Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikeforce:_Morituri):

> The setting of Strikeforce: Morituri is a continuity of its own and resembles no future seen in any other Marvel title. The Horde appear to have gathered trophies from residents of the Marvel Universe, including Captain America's Shield, the Silver Surfer's board and Galactus's helmet, as well as shelves of what appear to be power batteries used by DC Comics' Green Lantern Corps. At the time, that appeared to be an in-joke rather than a serious plot point.

From what I can tell, the rights to *Strikeforce: Morituri* are apparently disputed. Marvel’s consistent position is that Marvel (now Disney) completely owns the property. [Co-creator and writer Peter Gillis alleges that ownership is split 50%/50% with Marvel with Marvel’s ownership vested from co-creator and artist Brent Anderson, who at time of Morituri’s creation worked full-time for Marvel and so his half was a work-for-hire under Marvel.](https://bleedingcool.com/comics/recent-updates/a-new-legal-conflict-brewing-over-strikeforce-morituri-between-marvel-and-peter-gillis/)

There have been at least two aborted film projects, the first a collaboration of Marvel and SyFy called [A Thousand Days](https://www.google.com/amp/s/variety.com/2002/scene/markets-festivals/sci-fi-setting-its-sights-high-1117877626/amp/), originally planned to debut in 2003. The second was a film project pushed by Gillis circa 2011.

Marvel has generally proceeded to publish *Morituri* books, and registering trademarks, having released trade paperback collections of original series, and using *Morituri* in the comics like the 2014 *X-Force* appearance in current continuity.

IMDB maintains a *Strikeforce: Morituri* film [is in development](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt2012026/) with screenwriters Connor Cochran and Gillis, but this appears to be Gillis’ 2011 project.

What is the rights ownership situation of *Strikeforce: Morituri* as of 2021? Are there any film projects still alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The rights still appear to be disputed  as of December 2021

[Reference this 2014 statement from Connor Cochran who represented Gillis:](https://bleedingcool.com/comics/recent-updates/a-new-legal-conflict-brewing-over-strikeforce-morituri-between-marvel-and-peter-gillis/)

> I represent Peter Gillis, Strikeforce's creator, on this matter. It is Peter's legal position that he never signed any contracts with Marvel for Strikeforce and therefore he and Marvel are equal co-owners of the property. (Marvel's co-ownership is because artist Brent Anderson and Peter were co-creators of the book, and Brent was under contract with Marvel at the time.)

Additionally, Cochran threatens to sue to clarify matters if need be:

> Peter has been trying to settle this issue with Marvel definitively going back at least as far as 2002, but no agreement has yet been reached. Hard to say when that may finally happen, but obviously we'll take whatever legal steps are necessary to protect Peter's share of rights in his creation.

And he finished his statement confirming “where things stand” as of 2014, which appear to still hold true:

> Where things now stand is that we are preparing to reach out once more to Disney/Marvel to see if things can be settled peaceably, since that seems so obviously the better path. If our effort fails, we'll let the appropriate court decide the matter. This is all driven by Disney's ownership, the immense success of the films, and the possible problems with character ownership cause by years of sloppy recordkeeping, the bankruptcies, etc. They are moving to regularize and solidify their claims. We're doing the same. In the end I'm confident that Peter Gillis's co-ownership will be validated, one way or another.

I have searched for federal lawsuits involving Gillis v. Marvel, and including Cochran to no avail; it appears that ownership negotiations may either be ongoing, on hiatus, or otherwise held before one party or the other has sought to sue in US court for a resolution.

As confirmation of some veracity of Cochran’s 2014 statements, as well as serving as current state of things, is the [IMDB entry for the current Strikeforce: Morituri development.](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt2012026/) Both Cochran and Gillis are credited as screenwriters; this is apparently the 2011 production mentioned by Cochran — apparently stalled out for at least the past decade.